# Non-standard trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

I was learning how to solve $3\sin(t+\pi )=2$. Step one was isolating, then using inverse trig func., when it came to $t+\pi$ there was written that $t+\pi =0.730 \text{ radians}$, why is that? Could someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, indeed, $\sin^{-1} \frac{2}{3} \approx 0.7297$ in radians. The radian is the standard measure of angles in mathematics - you are free to use degrees as you wish, but be sure to write $\pi$ radians as $180$ degrees.

Comment: Sorry, but how? Beause 2/3=0.(6).

Comment: Before applying $\sin^{-1}$ to both sides you must divide by $3$ to yield $\sin (t + \pi) = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: I fathomed it. But how sin^-1(2/3)=0.7297?

Comment: You punch that into a calculator and it gives you that result. It is the angle (in radians) whose sine is $2/3$. Also, this is not an exact result - I rounded to four places.

Comment: I don't want to appear to be slow, but, if the calculator gives 0.(6) then how you now that in radians it is 0.729?

Comment: You press the $\sin^{-1}$ key after you type in $2/3$.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Is there another way of working it out? I mean by doing it on a sheet of paper.

Comment: Not really, unless you have access to trig tables (do a Google search for this if you wish). The arcsine of a general number does not usually have a nice form.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just because they didn't want to write out $\arcsin\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\approx 0.73$ every time. It is not really good practice to do so, however, since $0.73$ is not the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\sin(t+\pi)=-\sin(t)$$